How to edit grub.cfg file to boot two live linux distros from two different partitions on the same USB stick?
I have created a boot USB stick with Linux Mint 22 and Arch Linux 12-01-2024 on two seperate partitions and I am trying to use GRUB 2  to load them from the bootable USB stick. so I have the following partitions defined and the images flashed to sdb2 (mint) and sdb3 (arch):
sdb1 - EFI Partition (1 GB)
sdb2 - Linux Mint ext4 partition (15GB)
sdb3 - Arch Linux ext4/ partition (15gb)
I know that I cannot specify the device names (sdb1,sdb2,sdb3) in the grub.cfg file because those change after a reboot and the UUIDs do not.   The kernel and init.d have not been loaded yet. I am trying to specify the UUID itself within the grub.cfg file but I am not having any luck. I can get all the menu entries to work and I can get Linux Mint to boot the live-environment without an issue but when I attempt to pick any one of the Arch Linux entries I get an error from GRUB stating "missing file, must load kernel first". I know that GRUB is looking for the Arch kernel in the GPT2 partition under the casper directory where Linux Mint kernel is located, but I do not know how to tell GRUB where to find the Arch kernel which is located in the GPT3 partition under the arch directory.
I am trying to do a "dual boot" USB without using Ventoy because  I know that it can be done with GRUB and keep in mind that since this is a live bootable USB, "sudo install-grub" and "sudo update-grub" does nothing for the grub.cfg file and there is no fstab file to edit.
Here is a listing of my current grub.cfg that resides on the USB's EFI partition, I have the UUIDs that point to the partitions that I need to load commented out just for reference for now until I know where in the config file to put them:
loadfont unicode

set color_normal=white/black
set color_highlight=black/light-gray

insmod play
play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1 0 4 440 1

# https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Loopback.cfg"

# Search for the ISO volume
search --no-floppy --set=archiso_img_dev --file "${iso_path}"
probe --set archiso_img_dev_uuid --fs-uuid "${archiso_img_dev}"

# Get a human readable platform identifier
if [ "${grub_platform}" == 'efi' ]; then
    archiso_platform='UEFI'
    if [ "${grub_cpu}" == 'x86_64' ]; then
        archiso_platform="x64 ${archiso_platform}"
    elif [ "${grub_cpu}" == 'i386' ]; then
        archiso_platform="IA32 ${archiso_platform}"
    else
        archiso_platform="${grub_cpu} ${archiso_platform}"
    fi
elif [ "${grub_platform}" == 'pc' ]; then
    archiso_platform='BIOS'
else
    archiso_platform="${grub_cpu} ${grub_platform}"
fi

#menuentries 
menuentry "Start Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon 64-bit" --class linuxmint {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    #GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=3b5d4e95-771e-48bd-ae0d-4b61c80a8fa0
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper username=mint hostname=mint iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Start Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon 64-bit (compatibility mode)" {
    #GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=3b5d4e95-771e-48bd-ae0d-4b61c80a8fa0
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper username=mint hostname=mint iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll nomodeset --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Linux Mint OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    #GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=3b5d4e95-771e-48bd-ae0d-4b61c80a8fa0
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  oem-config/enable=true only-ubiquity boot=casper username=mint hostname=mint iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Arch Linux install medium (x86_64, ${archiso_platform})" --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --id 'archlinux' {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    #GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=e7151878-33fd-4d21-a0f2-c3cba821620d
    linux /arch/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz-linux archisobasedir=arch img_dev=UUID=${archiso_img_dev_uuid} img_loop="${iso_path}"
    initrd /arch/boot/x86_64/initramfs-linux.img
}
menuentry "Arch Linux install medium with speakup screen reader (x86_64, ${archiso_platform})" --hotkey s --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --id 'archlinux-accessibility' {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    #GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=e7151878-33fd-4d21-a0f2-c3cba821620d
    linux /arch/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz-linux archisobasedir=arch img_dev=UUID=${archiso_img_dev_uuid} img_loop="${iso_path}" accessibility=on
    initrd /arch/boot/x86_64/initramfs-linux.img
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
    exit 1
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
menuentry 'Memory test' {
    linux   /boot/memtest.efi
}
menuentry 'System shutdown' --class shutdown --class poweroff {
    echo 'System shutting down...'
    halt
}
menuentry 'System restart' --class reboot --class restart {
    echo 'System rebooting...'
    reboot
}
fi

I am assuming that the $[archiso_img_dev_UUID] and the $[iso_path] variables might have something to do with it, but I do not know how to edit those without disturbing my working Linnux Mint live session that resides on partition 2. It is only the Arch Linux kernel and RAM disk that will not boot that resides on partition 3.

If you run sudo grub-editenv list, what is the output? Also, do you have Secure Boot enabled?

I do not have secure boot enabled and when I issue the grub-editenv list command I get no output at all.
